# Display pdf file from absolute path

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdfviewer

I am using this code for creating pdf viewer in my application
https://amitpatriwala.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/pdf-viewer-in-asp-net/

it works fine when I give it a path for a file inside my application folders, ex: `displaypdf1.FilePath= @"~/MyFolder/" + Hello.pdf;`

but now I want to give this `displaypdf1.FilePath` an absolute path to read the pdf file which is not in my application folders, I tried but it didn't work!

Comment: If the IUSR or ASPNET account is given access to the path, it can read the file.

Answer (score 2):

A web page cannot access items that are outside of the website.  If you want the web page to reference files located in `D:\PDFs`, for example, you need to create a virtual directory in your website that points to "D:\PDFs".  Then the web pages can access them by ~/PDFs/Hello.pdf.

You'll also need to ensure that the website has appropriate permissions to access the directory.